# Can get coordinates from iPhone simulator, but can't get coordinates from iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I've run into something of a mysterious bug (to me). I have some code to pick out the user's current location on the iPhone SDK. It works fine on the iPhone simulator, but when I try to run it on the actual device, I get a weird error.

Here is the code (I am using ASIFormDataRequest to create a POST request):

```
ASIFormDataRequest * request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"testauthor" forKey:@"author"];
[request setPostValue:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:datum.location.coordinate.latitude] stringValue] forKey:@"latitude"];
NSLog(@"%f", datum.location.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"%f", datum.location.coordinate.longitude);
[request setPostValue:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:datum.location.coordinate.longitude] stringValue] forKey:@"longitude"];
[request setPostValue:datum.comment forKey:@"comment"];
```

On the simulator, NSLog does log both the latitude and longitude, but on the iPhone, it does not.

Even stranger, when I go through with the debugger on the device, I try "po datum.location", I get

```
<+###, -###> +/- 223.10m (speed 0.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2010-05-02 22:18:37 -0400
```

(### replaced by my location) but when I do "(gdb) po datum.location.coordinate" I get:

```
There is no member named coordinate.
```

Do you guys have any idea why this might happen? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Because `po` prints an object, and a `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not an object, it's a struct.

Comment: Hmm...that's true, but NSLog still doesn't seem to log the latitude and longitudes...